# How to enable communication between Substrate chain and web socket client

Tags: parity-bridges-common, websocket

I have a Substrate chain and web socket client, build in Rust. I am trying to figure out a way to enable communication between both of them.

I couldn't find way to create web socket server in Substrate chain.

Is there any way through which I can establish communication between chain and web socket client?